# AS3 advanced guide

Tags: actionscript-3

I think it's about time I asked. I'm learning AS3, apart from some childhood tricks with JavaScript it's my first p.language. Random tutorials teach the basics, like how to initiate a function, how to "listen", how to set variables etc. But the language is much bigger, I need a complex understanding of it. So randomly choosing tasks and finding ways to perform it may take pretty long. *I need an organized way to go through all the important, if not ALL, possibilities of AS3, step by step.*

I'm sure everyone who's willing to answer an AS3 tagged question knows a lot about this language and had his/her way of learning it, apart from using someone else's code til you understand it or asking people every time. I don't mind the last but I know I'll get many angry comment about my "serious_and_busy_people_forum" flooding. ;)

**So if you found some really good and complete, as well as clear, online tutorial, please share.**

As for examples of what I'm interested in right now, I'm about to see how to create many random instances that would share the same code like an object rotation-watching the closest one, storing information that may be shared by different scenes, creating smoother gravity, momenti, radii, setting paths of any shape for an object to go...

And yep, I don't need just a random tutorial or an Adobe dictionary - it's useful but only after you know everything and need a reminder, cause it only has a list of commands, classes, packages etc., and a very basic tutorial that is kinda below advanced. *I'd like to see what you consider your best helper in AS3 learning. =)*

Add: It's a question: what helped you most. I said I don't need random tutorials, I know how to google, I want people's opinion. Learn to read before you judge, insult, vote minus or act haughty. Especially if you're as useless as to provide 0 info on the subject. Pity I can't delete comments for flame.

If I provide a part of my code and ask for a better way - you help, but if I provide my level and ask for a better way to learn it all on my own - you attack? Wasting your time to write an offensive comment instead of help is, IMO, the bottom of intellect and culture.

Comment: You should read the FAQ. This is a Q/A site, not a "Find me a tutorial" site. I voted to close.

Comment: "It's a question: what helped you most" - Open ended, subjective questions are not well received either (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). Also, ranting is *extremely* frowned upon.

Comment: online tutorials are not the way to learn AS3.  buy books.  you should start with a beginner book about `C` programming to get the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apocalyptic0n3 is correct, you won't find the training you need here, however, I can recommend where to go from here.

**1:** Buy [a programming book](http://books.google.com/books?id=gUHX2fcLKxYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=AS3%20programming&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QTUdUdGbKIOy9gTpvoAw&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=AS3%20programming&f=false), or use any of the [freely available manuals](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/progAS_flex3.pdf).  Perhaps an [AS3 Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596526955.do), and definitely [an API reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html).

**2:** Learn general programming.  I don't mean "go learn C", I mean, know the difference between document code, and classes.  Know how and when to write functions, and how to use arguments.  Know the difference between the different variable types.  Know how to write loops.  Know your operators.

The problem with learning to program is no one can "teach" you how to write your program.  You need to know the tools, and the program you're trying to write will dictate what you write.  For this very reason, the most used documentation I use is the [API Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html) from Adobe.

- What are the methods of an array?  [Check the API.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#summaryTableMethod)
- How do you split a string at every return?  [Check the API.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29)
- How do you create a Vector number?  [Check the API.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#helpful-pod)
- etc...

It's actually very useful once you know how it's laid out, and once you realize that there's just way more there than you can put to memory in one "read-through", the importance of knowing everything about the language becomes unimportant.

**3:** Practice; in my opinion, the best training is doing.  So, pick a project, think through the logical steps *you* would take to do whatever it is you want your code to do, and research how you'd do that.

Finally, with regards to your particular area of interest, I've bought and loved Keith Peter's [Actionscript 3 Animation](http://books.google.com/books?id=nzyu5TytMEUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Actionscript%203%20animation&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CEMdUa-lEJH88QTA74DoDQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Actionscript%203%20animation&f=false) book.  It clearly explains all of your animation/collision/physics/3d-camera needs.

Comment: Well, you gave me some options and advice. Thanks for your time. I just wanna hear more people, know how they did it. One person counted pi before even making a wheel, another one took a stone and a piece of wood and hit one against another, third first made convenient tools, they all needed a cart. See, it takes to know the ways to choose from before just rushing into learning all I see. =)