# AS3 help needed if button1 of a movieclip && button2 of another movieclip clicked then gotoAndPlay

Tags: actionscript-3

I made a memory cards game which has 24 card images from which the user has to find 7 images in order to win. I am a begginer of actionscript 3 all the code is on frames instead of document or class files. All 24 card images are movieclips, on the set of 7 images i made a button with the second state in the same layer with the win image. All the cards are created dynamically from the library and not in the stage.
My problem is what i ever have tried untill now for the last code in order to win had no success i'm very desperate please help me .....I cannot make two movieclips to communicate via variables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yBwE.png)

Main timeline frame 6 has this code

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.display.Stage;

var objImage1:logo1 = new logo1;
var objImage2:pic2 = new pic2;
var objImage3:pic3 = new pic3;
var objImage4:logo2 = new logo2;
var objImage5:pic5  = new pic5;
var objImage6:pic6 = new pic6;
var objImage7:pic7 = new pic7;
var objImage8:logo3 = new logo3;
var objImage9:pic9 = new pic9;
var objImage10:pic10 = new pic10;
var objImage11:logo4 = new logo4;
var objImage12:pic12 = new pic12;
var objImage13:pic13 = new pic13;
var objImage14:pic14 = new pic14;
var objImage15:pic15 = new pic15;
var objImage16:logo5 = new logo5;
var objImage17:pic17 = new pic17;
var objImage18:logo6 = new logo6;
var objImage19:pic19 = new pic19;
var objImage20:pic20 = new pic20;
var objImage21:logo7 = new logo7;
var objImage22:pic22 = new pic22;
var objImage23:pic23 = new pic23;
var objImage24:pic24 = new pic24;
var sourceDeck:Array =[objImage1,objImage2,objImage3,objImage4,objImage5,objImage6,objImage7,objImage8,objImage9,objImage10,objImage11,objImage12,objImage13,objImage14,objImage15,objImage16,objImage17,objImage18,objImage19,objImage20,objImage21,objImage22,objImage23,objImage24];
var shuffledDeck:Array = new Array ();
var xValues:Array =["121","321","521","731","937","1136","120","320","520","732","938","1138","120","321","520","730","938","1135","121","322","520","732","938","1135"];
var yValues:Array =["173","173","173","173","173","173","346","346","346","346","346","346","534","534","534","534","534","534","716","716","716","716","716","716"];

function placeCards():void
{
for (var i:int = 0; i<sourceDeck.length; ++i)
{
    addChild(sourceDeck[i]);
    sourceDeck[i].x = int(xValues[i])+20;
    sourceDeck[i].y = int(yValues[i]);  
}
}
placeCards();
function removeCards():void
{
for (var i:int=0;  i<sourceDeck.length; ++i)

{
    removeChild(sourceDeck[i]);

}
}
    function shuffleCards():void
{
while(sourceDeck.length >0)
{
    var r:int=Math.floor(Math.random()*sourceDeck.length);
    shuffledDeck.push(sourceDeck[r]);
    sourceDeck.splice(r,1);
}
}
function placeShuffledCards():void
{
for (var i:int=0; i<shuffledDeck.length; ++i)
{
    addChild(shuffledDeck[i]);
    shuffledDeck[i].x = int(xValues[i]);
    shuffledDeck[i].y = int(yValues[i]);

}
}


function showShuffledCards():void

{   
removeCards();
shuffleCards();
placeShuffledCards();

}
showShuffledCards();
foo();

function foo():void {
    var x:int = 2; // you can use variables as you would normally

    // do something here

    var timer:Timer = new Timer(5000);
    var afterWaiting:Function = function(event:TimerEvent):void {
   timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, afterWaiting);
   timer = null;
   // 5 seconds have passed, now do something more


   objImage1.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage2.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage3.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage4.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage5.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage6.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage7.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage8.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage9.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage10.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage11.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage12.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage13.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage14.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage15.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage16.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage17.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage18.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage19.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage20.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage21.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage22.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage23.gotoAndPlay(10);
   objImage24.gotoAndPlay(10);
   // the scope is retained and you can still refer to the variables you
   // used earlier
   x += 2;
 }
 timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, afterWaiting);
    timer.start();

}
```

on each one of the seven buttons that each one is inside a movie clip I have this code:

```
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.text.*;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var success:Boolean = false;
var butpic1:SimpleButton;
butpic1.enabled = true;
addChild(butpic1);

butpic1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickpics);

function clickpics(event:MouseEvent):void {
gotoAndPlay(1);
var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();    
    myTextBox.text = "Σωστό Συνέχισε!";  
myTextBox.border = true;    
    myTextBox.borderColor = 0x000000; 
myTextBox.width = 180;    
myTextBox.height = 87;    
myTextBox.x = -77;    
myTextBox.y = -126; 
var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
myFormat.color = 000000;    
    myFormat.size = 24;
myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER
myTextBox.background = true;    
myTextBox.backgroundColor = 0xFFF000;
myTextBox.setTextFormat(myFormat);
    addChild(myTextBox);  

/*var Success=true;*/
//MovieClip(parent).Success2();
//trace(event.target.name);
var success=true;
if(MovieClip(root).butpic3 && butpic1 == success)
    {

    MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay("win");
    } 
//checking();
//trace(event.target);
//MovieClip(this.parent).success2();
//checking();
//MovieClip(root).check();
//trace("click: " + event.currentTarget.name);
}
//trace(MovieClip(root).but.butpic2);
/*function checking():void
{
if(butpic1 && MovieClip(root).butt.butpic3)
    {
    MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay("win");
    } else {
MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay("win");
}
}*/

/*function checking():void
{
if(MovieClip(root).Symbol1 && MovieClip(root).button2)
    {

    MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay("win");
    } 
}*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must warn you that putting code into MovieClips is an outmoded approach, and should be avoided.  Putting code into different frames invariably causes more headaches.  However, after reading through your code, I believe this should answer your question.

Note that most of the explanation is in the comments of the code, so read on.

```
import flash.text.*;
import flash.display.Stage;

/*You need a reference to each of these library instances, but you were creating
two references to them; (1) a variable, and (2) an array entry. You can create
this data once, thinking of each object as a individual "card", and add any
additional data to it together in the same place.  Most importantly, this
structure allows us to use array.sortOn().*/
var deck:Array = [
    {"img":new logo1, "valid":true},
    {"img":new pic2, "valid":false},
    {"img":new pic3, "valid":false},
    {"img":new logo2, "valid":true},
    {"img":new pic5, "valid":false},
    {"img":new pic6, "valid":false},
    {"img":new pic7, "valid":false},
    {"img":new logo3, "valid":true},
    {"img":new pic9, "valid":false},
    {"img":new pic10, "valid":false},
    {"img":new logo4, "valid":true},
    {"img":new pic12, "valid":false},
    {"img":new pic13, "valid":false},
    {"img":new pic14, "valid":false},
    {"img":new pic15, "valid":false},
    {"img":new logo5, "valid":true},
    {"img":new pic17, "valid":false},
    {"img":new logo6, "valid":true},
    {"img":new pic19, "valid":false},
    {"img":new pic20, "valid":false},
    {"img":new logo7, "valid":true},
    {"img":new pic22, "valid":false},
    {"img":new pic23, "valid":false},
    {"img":new pic24, "valid":false}
];

/*You mentioned you were having difficulty getting your MovieClips to communicate
with eachother and track the success of valid clicks to "win".  You can see we've
added a property "valid" which let's us know if it's a valid option for "winning".
We'll later add the state of it's "success".*/

// Because your locations were explicit pairs, it's also a good idea to keep these
// together, if nothing more than for maintainability & legibility.
var locs:Array = [
    {"x":121, "y":173},
    {"x":321, "y":173},
    {"x":521, "y":173},
    {"x":731, "y":173},
    {"x":937, "y":173},
    {"x":1136, "y":173},
    {"x":120, "y":346},
    {"x":320, "y":346},
    {"x":520, "y":346},
    {"x":732, "y":346},
    {"x":938, "y":346},
    {"x":1138, "y":346},
    {"x":120, "y":534},
    {"x":321, "y":534},
    {"x":520, "y":534},
    {"x":730, "y":534},
    {"x":938, "y":534},
    {"x":1135, "y":534},
    {"x":121, "y":716},
    {"x":322, "y":716},
    {"x":520, "y":716},
    {"x":732, "y":716},
    {"x":938, "y":716},
    {"x":1135, "y":716}
];

// Nulling of the timer & removal of the event listener wasn't strictly necessary.
// Simply use the second argument of Timer(millisecondDelay, repeatCount).
var timer:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1);

init();
function init():void {
    // Here, we've replaced your foo() with an initialization function where all
    // one-time stuff gets done.  
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, afterWaiting);
    timer.start();

    // Rather than checking within each card, we'll add the checks from the main stage.
    // This also means you can get rid of the code inside the clips.
    for each (var card:Object in deck) {
        card.img.butpic1.addEventListener("click", checkCard);
    }

    showShuffledCards();
}


function showShuffledCards():void {   
    removeCards();
    shuffleCards();
    placeCards();
}

function removeCards():void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
        // Ensure it needs to be removed, before attempting it.
        if (deck[i].img.parent != null) {
            removeChild(deck[i].img);
        }
    }
}

function shuffleCards():void {
    /*Rather than keeping two arrays, and the shuffle only working once, we can
    use sortOn() the existing array by changing the value of the property we're
    sorting with.  This effectively shuffles the deck, and allows us to shuffle
    indefinitely.*/
    for each (var card:Object in deck) {
        card.order = Math.random();
    }

    deck.sortOn("order", Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC);
}

function placeCards():void {
    // placeShuffledCards was doing the same thing as this function,
    // so we simply use this one.
    for (var i:int = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
        addChild(deck[i].img);
        deck[i].img.x = locs[i].x + 20;
        deck[i].img.y = locs[i].y;  
    }
}

function afterWaiting(event:TimerEvent):void {
    // Rather than explicityly name each object, because we have them in a fancy
    // array, we can write the command once, and call it on each card in the deck.
    for each (var obj:MovieClip in deck) {
        obj.gotoAndPlay(10);
    }
}

function checkCard(e:Event):void {
    // Search the deck for this card.
    var successCount = 0;
    for each (var card:Object in deck) {
        if (e.currentTarget == card.img && card.valid) {
            // If the card clicked is valid for winning, 
            // add the text and update its status.
            card.img.gotoAndPlay(1);

            var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();    
            myTextBox.text = "Σωστό Συνέχισε!";  
            myTextBox.border = true;    
            myTextBox.borderColor = 0x000000; 
            myTextBox.width = 180;    
            myTextBox.height = 87;    
            myTextBox.x = -77;    
            myTextBox.y = -126; 
            var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
            myFormat.color = 000000;    
            myFormat.size = 24;
            myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER
            myTextBox.background = true;    
            myTextBox.backgroundColor = 0xFFF000;
            myTextBox.setTextFormat(myFormat);
            card.img.addChild(myTextBox);

            card.success = true;
        }

        // While we're looping through the deck, we'll also count up the number
        // of successful clicks.
        if (card.hasOwnProperty("success") && card.success == true) {
            successCount++;
        }
    }

    // If the count of successful clicks is 7, go to the "win" frame.
    if (successCount == 7) {
        gotoAndPlay("win")
    }
}
```

**Addendum**

Since you haven't posted many questions yet, you may not be familiar with StackOverflow's rules/habits.  When posting code, please update your question with that content.  It's easier to read, and can be formatted (unlike comments).

*How to debug*

Beyond checkmarking "Permit Debugging" in the publish settings & holding control-shift-enter to launch in debugging mode, all you must do is familiarize yourself with the frames available; notably "Call Stack", "Variables", "Output", and your syntax editor.

[image: Code break]

In this case, you can see the program stopped in the `init()` function on line 90.  The "Output" window is telling us that something doesn't exist, and from what's listed on 90, that'd have to be `card`, `img`, `logo1`, or `checkCard`.

Now, we know, the first two exist, and the last one exists, but logo1 (and specifically in at this location) does not exist.  On the left you can see the variables available to the current scope of the code at this point in the program's runtime.  We can dig inside of `card` and find the `img` property, and from here we can indeed confirm there is not `logo1` property inside of `img`.  Pretty simple once you know how the windows work, right?  :)

As you did share you document, (and I'll repeat, because you're relatively new to SO), I've taken the liberty of fixing your fla file.  I've also taken it a step further to show you where you might take your code next, removing the frame code, and creating your functionality/User-interface entirely from code with zero embedded images.  You can [download it from Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wx7uuim98auxhlb/memory_game.zip?dl=0).

[image: memory game]

Comment: My bad, that should have a variable declaration before it: `for each (var obj:MovieClip in deck) {`

Comment: thank you for your help there is a mistake Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 6, Line 139 1084: Syntax error: expecting in before colon. the mistake is on this line: for each (obj:MovieClip in deck) {

Comment: these errors came up TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at game_fla::MainTimeline/init()[game_fla.MainTimeline::frame6:92]
 at game_fla::MainTimeline/frame6()[game_fla.MainTimeline::frame6:82]
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
 at game_fla::MainTimeline/clickstart()[game_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:5]

Comment: I don't see a `clickStart()` function in the code you shared, and my `line 92` is a blank line.  To debug this properly, build your swf in Debug mode and check your Call Stack.  From there you should be able to step through where the code was and what property it can't find/access.

Comment: On frame 1 I have a button with this script stop();
 
startbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickstart);
function clickstart(e:MouseEvent):void {
 MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(6);
 
} the user must click on it in order to play the game  for this script the debuger gives me this error when is loading without any clicking Attempting to launch and connect to Player using URL C:\Users\persa\Desktop\game\game.swf
[SWF] C:\Users\persa\Desktop\game\game.swf - 208550 bytes after decompression

Comment: when i click gives this TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at game_fla::MainTimeline/init()[game_fla.MainTimeline::frame6:92]
 at game_fla::MainTimeline/frame6()[game_fla.MainTimeline::frame6:82]
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
 at game_fla::MainTimeline/clickstart()[game_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:5]

Comment: On frame 6 I have all the code that you post me, frame 6 line 92 has this  card.img.logo1.addEventListener("click", checkCard); where logo1 is the class name of pic1 I have done same for all 24 images I have upload here my fla if you want to see it http://eragkousi.gr/game.fla

Comment: On meantime I'm reading manuals for debuging I feel so useless :(

Comment: how can i combine init() with my first frame button as there i think is the first conflict ?

Comment: Answer updated.  I'm going to bed now, as I've stayed up waaaay too late (though it was fun)!

Comment: Your are my savor honestly to write the code I wrote I was working for a month 16hours daily and the weekends all day long :) I imagine is not allowed to post files with code, I'll read the terms, Do you have any good source to recommend me for actionscript 3? I hope one day to help you too.

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful!  For posting guidelines, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  As for learning AS3, O'Reilly has a number of books I recommend, and the API Reference I use all the time.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880593/as3-advanced-guide/14883028#14883028